# getting error when use calabash-android 'run command

Tags: calabash, calabash-android

I have setup ruby,ant,jdk,sdk,calabash-android.but when I try:

```
calabash-android run appName.apk
```

it didn't work. there are some prompt：

```
D:\Software_Tools\Eclipse_Files\work_space\AndroidDemoProject\calabash>calabash-d-0.5.9/lib/calabash-android/helpers.rb:180:in `extract_signature_algorithm_name': No signature algorithm names found: (RuntimeError)
别名: androiddebugkey
条目类型: PrivateKeyEntry
```

Comment: Did you run 'calabash-android resign' and 'calabash-android build' first?

Answer (score 2):

Can you upgrade to Calabash Android 0.5.10.pre2?

This has solved the version for other users.

Answer (score 1):

I downgraded to calabash-android 0.5.5 and it works like a charm now.

Comment: I am glad it worked to downgrade, but we recommend that you try to keep up with the most recent version.  Did the 0.5.10.pre2 version not work for you?